# Is there a Function or set of functions on Google Sheets that reacts every multiple?

Tags: google-sheets

Okay, say I have 5 cells. Each with varying amounts.
I want a function that: If(Sum(b2:b6) {greater or equal to a multiple}, True, False

So every time the total value of those cells is greater to or equal to a multiple of, say 50, so if it lands on 50n+1 or something, it'll react as if it hit 50n.

Comment: I'm sure what you are describing makes sense to you. But it is not clear at all to me. It is best if you set up a spreadsheet, enter data into Column B and then *hand-enter* into Column C the results you expect a formula to produce. Off to the right, in Column D, explain how those results in Column C were determined based on the data in Column C. Then share a link to that sample spreadsheet here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not multiplying but adding numbers in range, since you are using "SUM" in function. In case, here is a solution:

```
=IF((SUM(B2:B6))>=50;TRUE;FALSE)
```

> Note: This code is written with Norwegian format settings. Change ";" in formula with "," for American format settings.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

sounds like:

```
=IF(SUM(B2:B6)>=50; 50; )
```